# Cannot connect to raspberry pi in the same subnet over ssl

Tags: networking

I set up JupyterHub on my rpi3 via ssh, and want to access it from another computer (not through ssh, but through `<rpi3's ip address>:<port>`)

My computer and my rpi3 are on the same subnet (192.168.1.14 and 192.168.1.20).

Using a second ssh session, I verified that the server is indeed running at 127.0.0.1:8081. But I'm unable to connect to it even within that session at 192.168.1.20:443.

Why and how to fix?

[image: ssl pi description]

The configuration is in the image.

Comment: Please post your jupyter config. You may also want to read this: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html  especially the section on listening on all interfaces.

Comment: You also need to connect with https and it does not appear that you are.

Answer (score 0):

If it is `ip_tables`, you can run these commands in order to fix the issue:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install ufw`
3. `sudo ufw enable`
4. `sudo ufw allow 443` (Where `443` is the port number to allow.)

There is documentation available for Ubuntu for this which is a similar process to the process for the Pi. This documentation is available at [UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

EDIT: As this [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/cannot-connect-to-raspberry-pi-in-the-same-subnet-over-ssl/68601#comment107041_68599) very rightly said, you must connect over HTTPS.